# How To Get TableviewCell Selected Check Mark Row Values Using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, tableview

I need to create `tableviewcell` `checkmark` selected row `title` label and `detail` label values get after clicking the submit button.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil )
    {
        cell =[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    if ([indexPath compare:self.lastIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) 
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } 
    else 
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return cell;
}

// UITableView Delegate Method

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"Section:%ld Row:%ld selected and its data is %@ %@",(long)indexPath.section,(long)indexPath.row,cell.sector_Label.text,cell.textLabel.text);
    selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
    [tableView reloadData];
}



- (IBAction)Submit_Click:(id)sender {

// Here I need to get tableview cell check mark selected cell label values.

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
-(IBAction)Submit_Click:(id)sender {

    // Here I need to get tableview cell check mark selected cell label values.
    if (selectedIndex >= 0) {
        NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:0];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSLog(@"detailTextLabel: %@", cell.detailTextLabel.text);
        NSLog(@"title: %@", cell.textLabel.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: lastIndexPath - getting error! Property 'lastIndexPath' not found on object of type '*'

Comment: It is same variable name used in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method you given.

Comment: @Sanju  selectedIndex should be NSIndexPath type, and in your 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath'  delegate method : selectedIndex = indexPath; Then use this answer written by bunty

Comment: @iMeng, I got the indexPathForSelectedRow method as shorter way to get the current selected cell.

Comment: cell = [tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndex]; its showing no null error buddy

Comment: @bunty yeah, I notice you change answer just now.

Comment: Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSIndexPath * _Nonnull' is disallowed with ARC

Comment: Check now, I hope you have only one section.

Comment: Its not working getting only Tableview last index values @bunty

Comment: This is because you have stored only one selectedIndex value for selected cell. Store all selected cell in an array, put above code in for loop traversing all indexes stored in that array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexPathsForSelectedRows`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell.isSelected)
    {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
      [cell setSelected:YES animated:YES]
    }
}

-(IBAction)Submit_Click:(id)sender {

// Here I need to get tableview cell check mark selected cell label values.
 NSArray *indexes = [self.tableview indexPathsForSelectedRows];
 if (indexes.count > 0)
 {
   //do your stuff as you get selected row index array
 }
}
```